# How do i correct an error in script below

Tags: excel, vba, button, runtime, xlsm

```
Private Sub CONFIRM_Click()


If TextBox4.Value = "" And ComboBox3.Value = "" And TextBox7.Value = "" And TextBox5.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Thank you for providing the requested information"
Exit Sub

  ElseIf TextBox4.Value <> "" Or ComboBox3.Value <> "" Or TextBox7.Value <> "" Or TextBox5.Value <> "" Then

SecondRecord rng.Rows.Count: InitData: InitRowSource

End If
EnvoiMailNP

MsgBox "Your request has been tranfered to Procurement & Vendor Management Unit, this platform will close automatically"
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.SAVE
UserForm2_Terminate
Workbooks("REQUEST MANAGEMENT TOOL.xlsm").Close True
End Sub
```

Error runtime 9 occurs on line
`Workbooks("REQUEST MANAGEMENT TOOL.xlsm").Close True`

Comment: Are you certain that workbook is open at the time?  The previous statements are refreshing and saving the active workbook, but then you're specifically trying to close a named workbook.  It's also possible that the workbook name `"REQUEST MANAGEMENT TOOL.xlsm"` is throwing the error because it is not a fully qualified pathname (i.e. `C:\Temp\REQUEST MANAGEMENT TOOL.xlsm"`), and so Excel can't find it.

Comment: @PeterT Just a friendly tip: Excel doesn't need the path to close a workbook.

Comment: Just press the Help Button on the error message and will take you to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9) with the reason: _You referenced a nonexistent collection member_. Then follow @PeterT advice.

Comment: Thx a lot. We had changed the name of the workbook (save as) but the code line refered to the old name. After modifying the name of the active workbook in the code line, the script worked perfectly.

Comment: @EEM - I completely agree that Excel doesn't need the filename to close the current workbook. But if the code is trying to close another (already open) workbook that is not the `ActiveWorkbook` or `ThisWorkbook`, then it's possible to close another workbook with the name. I don't believe this is the case for OP, but I should have been more clear in my comment.